# Mostrar solamente veterinarias en mapa de Google Maps con Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-api

Tengo creado un mapa potenciado por Google Maps, donde ya obtengo la ubicación del usuario perfectamente. Lo que necesito hacer es mostrar todas las veterinarias que existan que estén en Google Maps. La única solución que vi fue agregar Markers custom, pero sería muy tardado agregar uno por uno y larguísimo el codigo. ¿Hay alguna manera de evitar eso? ¿que se pueda automatizar con alguna api o algo?

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que ya haya alguna API con las coordenadas de las veterinarias, pero no sé si habrá algo así y que sea gratuito. Lo más seguro es que tengas que montar tú la API y consultar los datos. No te aconsejo poner los datos en bruto dentro de la app, porque para modificarlos, tendrás que actualizarla.

Answer (score 0):

Yo trabajé anteriormente con algo así, lo que debes hacer es manejar radios dentro de tu mapa, cada vez que mueves el mapa obtener la ubicación del centro del mapa (Está en el Widget de Google Maps), y sumando latitud y longitud, obtener un radio, solamente dentro de ese radio tu pintas los Custom Markers, una vez muevas el mapa volverá a actualizarse la ubicación de centro de mapa y se pintarán solo los markers necesarios.